# Can I sleep my laptop during a MySQL import?

Tags: mysql, osx-lion

I'm importing my company's entire DB into a local database. Would closing my laptop, thus putting it to sleep, make me have to start over, or would it recover as normal?

It's a MacBook Pro with OSX Lion.

---

EDIT:

I'm closing it up and heading home; hopefully I don't have to restart this, but it would be good to know for future reference. I'll let you know!

---

EDIT2:

made it home, according to `top`, `ps` and `jobs` it's still chugging along...

Comment: if sleep shuts down your harddrive, then I am gonna guess it will stop the import.

Comment: Probably. However, you can configure what closing your laptop does in Control Panel -> Power Options. If you just want to close the lid, you can set it to turn off the screen instead of sleeping.

Comment: Since it is a _local_ database, I don't see why sleep would abort the import. That would be like getting _all_ ongoing writes to any files corrupted the moment you sleep the machine.

Comment: Why close it if you're unsure?

Comment: @IvanNevostruev I want to go home, but I still have a lot of work to do...

Comment: @JKirchartz you should be leave it open and disable all power saving options

Comment: meh... forget it, I'm closing it up & heading home; hopefully I don't have to restart this! (but it would be gtk for future reference) ... if you're voting to close as off-topic, please select superuser!

Comment: This is exactly why dev environments on centralized servers exist. Developing locally is never a good idea.

Comment: @MikePurcell where do you think I'm copying from? the DB times out when I try to connect over VPN...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any I/O operations in progress are suspended on sleep and are resumed when your system wakes up.  Simple I/O operations such as copying or moving files within a hard drive will continue normally, but putting a computer to sleep may interfere with operations that expect continuity and do not guarantee successful continuation after resuming from sleep, such as programs that are communicating with each other in real time.  This includes clients communicating with servers.

In your case, because the client-server connection is on the local machine and database systems tend to be robust against these types of interruptions, you were able to continue without problems.  However, if the operation involves a network connection, such as a download, the connection is dropped on sleep and is started anew on resuming, terminating any network transfer in progress.

Answer (score 0):

I would not sleep it just to be safe. That you will not have to redo anything.